# Why does IEnumerable.Where method allow a predicate that can change the data?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for an explanation as to why the following line of code is allowed to compile:

```
var results = someCollection.Where(x => x.SomeBooleanProperty = true);
```

Note the use of the single equality operator (maybe the developer was in SQL mode), which is a very easy mistake to make. This compiles and when the results are evaluated (e.g. `someCollection.ToList()`) it changes the flag to true on the entire collection!!

If you are using entity framework, or any other ORM for that matter, then this could be detected as a change. I’ve just come across this issue in production code but fortunately it was only causing a minor (but completely bamboozling) issue on a read-only screen. Just imagine the horrible logic and data problems that could be caused by this if the data was actually persisted.

Just to make sure I wasn't going mad and that it does actually change the data I wrote a test which fails:

```
[Test]
public void Test_because_im_scared()
{
    var falseProperty = new TestModel {BooleanProperty = false};
    var trueProperty = new TestModel {BooleanProperty = true};

    var list = new List<TestModel>{falseProperty, trueProperty};

    var results = list.Where(x => x.BooleanProperty = true);

    Assert.IsFalse(falseProperty.BooleanProperty);
    Assert.IsTrue(trueProperty.BooleanProperty);

    //all fine so far, now evaluate the results
    var evaluatedResults = results.ToList();

    Assert.IsFalse(falseProperty.BooleanProperty);  //test fails here!
    Assert.IsTrue(trueProperty.BooleanProperty);
}
```

Comment: Why are you comparing boolean properties to begin with? `var results = someCollection.Where(x => x.SomeBooleanProperty)` will do.

Comment: `single equality operator` - no such thing. It is the _assignment_ operator.

Comment: And are you sure that *on its own* this will make changes to the database using EF? I wouldn't expect it to...

Comment: @Oded I assume that was a contrived example

Comment: Good question. I didn't write the code though, I just found the bug.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I know there's no such thing and that this is an assignment operator.

Comment: Fine, but you didn't name it that in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet My question is simply why the Where method allows such a dangerous predicate. There's no compiler warning and even ReSharper doesn't warn about it. I will write an integration test to see if EF detects it as a change.

Comment: @Cat: Yes, I've seen the request for an explanation now, and edited the question. I wouldn't like to say what EF will do if you try to propagate updates explicitly, but I strongly suspect that just executing the *query* won't make changes.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. The reason it's a concern for our code is we're using a unit of work pattern which keeps a live context for each business operation, so when we call save changes on our unit of work all changes since the entities were loaded are persisted.

Comment: @Cat: Right. It makes sense to be concerned about that (although do you have code review? I would expect direct equality comparisons with `true` and `false` to be flagged up in code review, and this should have failed unit tests anyway) but I think it would be worth editing your question to be more circumspect about its assertion that "If you are using entity framework, or any other ORM for that matter, then this would be detected as a change and then persisted to the database."

Comment: @JonSkeet Have a look at the unit test AlanT wrote to show that this can happen with integer assignment too. We are just starting code reviews and developer is aware not to do this, but we all have bad coding days and it's an easy mistake to make. We have unit tests around the code that had this issue but they didn't catch for reasons I don't have time to explain. I'll remove 'and then persisted to the database'.

Comment: @Cat: The integer assignment version wouldn't happen accidentally though - there's an assignment *and* a comparison. I can believe that a developer could write `=` instead of `==`, but I don't think they're write `(x = 17) == 17` instead of `x == 17` without noticing.

Comment: Well, I concede it's unlikely but the problem is that it *can* happen. This is the sort of thing that keeps me up at night :)

Comment: [Someone asked a similar question about four years ago on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/5574e147-5be0-4520-b7b7-2b4aab42c130/), but there wasn't any answer...

Answer (score 9):

The `=` operator in fact does two things:

- Set the field/property on the left-hand side to the value on the right-hand side.
- Return the newly assigned value.

This is also the reason why statements like this work:

```
object item;
while ((item = getItem()) != null)   
  processItem(item);
```

Comment: there we go, i was about to catch yo uon that one! ;)

Comment: Been coding too much in dynamically typed languages lately ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
x => x.SomeBooleanProperty = true
```

This lambda means - for x, assign `true` to `SomeBooleanProperty`. The result of the assignment is the value `true` as well.

If this is changed to:

```
x => x.SomeBooleanProperty
```

The lambda means - for x return the value of `SomeBooleanProperty`.

Comment: The OP should definitely not be using a lambda like `x.BooleanProperty == true`. It's just redundant and error-prone. Good suggestion.

Comment: Understood and agreed. It was a simple mistake. I'm thinking I need to carefully rephrase my question as I understand why it compiles just not *why it's allowed to*. I suppose I should raise it with Microsoft :)

Answer (score 3):

It compiles because it's a valid `Func<T, bool>`. There's no way for the compiler to tell that in this case, it shouldn't allow that.

Comment: I don't know the ins and outs but would be useful if it could at least warn about there being an assignment operator in the predicate. Oh well, one to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is related to the fact that

```
x => x.BooleanProperty = true
```

evaluates to true and is thus a valid where() predicate

I tried it with ints and was able to get the same behaviour.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_because_im_scared() {
    var falseProperty = new TestModel { BooleanProperty = false };
    var trueProperty = new TestModel { BooleanProperty = true };

    var list = new List<TestModel> { falseProperty, trueProperty };

    var results = list.Where(x => (x.IntProperty = 17) == 17) ;

    Assert.IsTrue(list.All(itm => itm.IntProperty == 0));

    //all fine so far, now evaluate the results 
    var evaluatedResults = results.ToList();

    Assert.IsTrue(list.All(itm => itm.IntProperty == 0)); // fails here, all 17

}

private class TestModel {
   public bool BooleanProperty { get; set; }
   public int IntProperty { get; set; }
}
```

AFAIK this is unintended behaviour, the IEnumerable<> extensions should all return new enumerables and not change the original but I have not seen that guaranteed anywhere.

It looks like it could be used as a pseudo foreach() but I wouldn't recommend it :-/

Alan.